# Who was the person during the credits of Thor: The Dark World

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

During the credits of *Thor: The Dark World*,

> Volstagg and Sif give what looks like a small container of the main story weapon "Aether"

to this collector. when this person took the package, he says:

> "one down, five to go".

Which I'm guessing is some reference to

> Thanos and his lust for power,

but who was this collector person?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Collector is one of the [Elders of the Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elders_of_the_Universe), which is a group of immortals that are each the last of their respective species, and each of which is obsessed with a single activity as a means of preventing boredom from overcoming their eternal lives. Shockingly, the Collector's hobby is collecting things.

The things he likes to collect include superheroes, and so he is a villain in the comics. As he  is slated to appear in the *Guardians of the Galaxy* film, he will probably be the villain of the piece there.

In the comics he and

> five of his fellow Elders each possessed an Infinity Gem, and these were taken by Thanos of Titan, who then used them to create the Infinity Gauntlet. This granted him godhood, allowing him to perform such feats as killing half the population of the universe; killing the combined might of Earth's heroes; defeating the cosmic beings of the universe (Including Galactus, the embodiments of time, chaos, order, love and hate and even Death herself, and a few more -- basically the Big Scary Things of the Marvel Universe); and finally it allows him to defeat the anthropomorphic personification of the universe itself and essentially become capital-G all-powerful God.

So the scene is likely to tie into the *Guardians of the Galaxy* film, and the eventual Thanos plot (which will presumably culminate in Avengers 3).

Comment: This stuff's capital-E Epic!